# How to draw on axis from pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

How can I draw on an `axis` from `pgfplots`? I already found out, that I somehow have to use `axis cs:` in front of the coordinates (what does `cs` mean?), but the following example does not draw the ellipse:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \draw (axis cs:0,0) ellipse (1cm,1cm);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the general way of drawing on an axis plot?

Comment: Your example works for me with supplied limits (`xmin`, etc.) and `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}` (the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) (section 4.16 “Custom Annotations”) demands for `> 1.5.1`). `cs` stands for coordinate system. By the way, the (old) syntax for the ellipse is `(1cm and 1cm)`, although I recommend `[x radius=1cm, y radius=1cm]`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Your comment is the best answer that I am aware of. You should probably turn it into an answer

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I have answered. Hopefully you can agree with everything that is said. I don’t often find my self using the `pgfplots` package, so I rather leave a comment or a suggestion (or wait for the author’s approval `;)`).

Comment: Side note, in newer versions/compatibility mode you can drop the `axis cs` [tikz pgf - Make "axis cs" the default coordinate system in a PGFPlots plot - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208488/make-axis-cs-the-default-coordinate-system-in-a-pgfplots-plot)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let’s break it down:

The “older syntax” for the `ellipse` path operator is `ellipse (<x radius> and <y radius>)`.

But, there is a newer and better syntax. I agree here with the manual:

> Note: There also exists an older syntax for circles [and ellipses],
>   where the radius of the circle is given in parentheses right after the
>   circle command as in `circle (1pt)`. Although this syntax is a bit
>   more succinct, it is harder to understand for readers of the code and
>   the use of parentheses for something other than a coordinate is
>   ill-chosen.
>
> — PGF manual, section 14.7 “The circle and Ellipse Operations”, p. 148

The following syntax is much more readable:

```
\draw (axis cs:0,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=1cm];
```

and you could also add `scale` and `rotate` options or can use them in the `every circle` style or …

But still, no output of an ellipse. `:(`

Reading section 4.16 “Custom Annotations”, pp. 263ff of the [`pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) we can find a few examples using the `ellipse` path operator, where axes limits are always given. These are needed if the `axis` environment does not contain one single plot.

So, this works:

```
\begin{axis}%[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1]
  \addplot {x^2 - x + 4};
  \draw (axis cs:0,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=1cm];
\end{axis}
```

This does not:

```
\begin{axis}%[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1]
  \draw (axis cs:0,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=1cm];
\end{axis}
```

But this:

```
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1]
  \draw (axis cs:0,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=1cm];
\end{axis}
```

---

You can also use radii given in `pgfplots` direction vectors, these automatically use the `axis direction cs` (`cs` stands for Coordinate System, which itself has a big chapter in the PGF manual). To do this you will need to set at least  `compat=1.5.1`.

Simply omit the dimension units and `pgfplots` automatically assumes the `axis direction cs`:

```
\draw (axis cs:0,0) ellipse [x radius=2,  y radius=.5];
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1]
%    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \draw (axis cs:0,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=1cm];
    \draw (axis cs:0,0) ellipse [x radius=2,  y radius=.5];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The answer is good. In addition, there is one further useful option: if you *omit* the unit `cm`, pgfplots will assume that the radii are expressed in axis units (requires `compat=1.7` - or was it `1.6`?) .

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I thought I have described this with the latter paragraph, maybe it was easily skipped. I have added a few words and separated the paragraph a little bit more. According to the manual (p. 266 in the `1.7-260-ge1fb941` revision`), it requires `1.5.1`.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that and thanks for the clarification!