# Make "axis cs" the default coordinate system in a PGFPlots plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to know if there is a way to specify `axis cs` to be the default coordinate system inside a plot in PGFPlots, so I don't have to type `axis cs:` in front of every coordinate pair.
Here's a MWE that shows what I mean (the actual plot is irrelevant).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
              xmin=0,
              xmax=80,
              ymin=0,
              ymax=80,
              grid=major,
             ]
  \fill [green, opacity=0.5] (axis cs:14,14) -- (axis cs:80,47) -- (axis cs:80,80) -- (axis cs:47,80) -- cycle;
  \fill [red, opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (axis cs:80,0) -- (axis cs:80,47) -- (axis cs:14,14) -- (axis cs:47,80) -- (axis cs:0,80) -- cycle;
  \draw [thick] (axis cs:47,80) -- (axis cs:14,14) -- (axis cs:80,47);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question: [tikz pgf - \draw not working inside axis environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210821/draw-not-working-inside-axis-environment/210823#210823); [tikz pgf - Nodes not appearing on TikZpicture - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592662/nodes-not-appearing-on-tikzpicture?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current stable version of `pgfplots` is version 1.11 (released August 2014). It supports this if you write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` into your preamble. Without this statement, it will remain compatible with the old behavior.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
              xmin=0,
              xmax=80,
              ymin=0,
              ymax=80,
              grid=major,
             ]
  \fill [green, opacity=0.5] (14,14) -- (80,47) -- (80,80) -- (47,80) -- cycle;
  \fill [red, opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (80,0) -- (80,47) -- (14,14) -- (47,80) -- (0,80) -- cycle;
  \draw [thick] (47,80) -- (14,14) -- (80,47);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, `axis cs` _is_ the default coordinate system in the current version of `pgfplots`?

Comment: Right. Provided you say `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`.